# store result of select in variable ms sql

Tags: sql-server

I want to store the result of a table in a variable. I know the result is always one column and one record. Here is my code:

```
if ((select count(id) from Categorie where naam = 'Hobbyclub') = 1)
    begin
        declare @id int set select id from Categorie where naam = 'Hobbyclub';

        insert into Items(naam, categorieID) values ('Naaien', @id);

        print 'ok';
    end
else 
    print 'nok';
```

It gives following error near the keyword `set`:

> Incorrect syntax

How can I store the first record and first column store in `@id`.

Note that `categorieID` *(by the `insert` statement)* is also a record with type `int`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to assign a variable:

```
DECLARE @id INT;
SELECT @id = id FROM Categorie WHERE naam = 'Hobbyclub';
```

Here's another:

```
DECLARE @id INT;
SET @id = (SELECT id FROM …);
```

If you are working with SQL Server 2008 or later, the last can be abbreviated to:

```
DECLARE @id INT = (SELECT id FROM …);
```